# Xpath: how to find tables with header names equals 'headerName'

Tags: xml, xpath

Using xpath to find tables which match: header text at column 1 is "header1" AND header text at column2 is "header2"...etc.

Comment: sorry forgot to say finding html tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about HTML tables: `//table[thead/tr/th[1] = 'header1' and thead/tr/th[2] = 'header2']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//table[columns[1]/header/text() = 'header1' and columns[2]/header/text() = 'header2']
```